# Subclass method not getting resolved

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

I have the following structure:

```
import abc


class AbstractParent:
    pass

class AbstractChild(AbstractParent):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class Child(AbstractChild):
    def foo(self):
        print('!')

class A:
    def __init__(self, x: AbstractParent):
        self.x = x

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x: Child):
        super().__init__(x=x)
    
    def test(self):
        return self.x.foo()      # Unresolved attribute reference 'foo' for class 'AbstractParent'
```

What I would expect is that since `Child` is a subclass of `AbstractParent` and `Child` has a method `foo`, and since `x` is being declared as a `Child` in class `B`, that `foo` is able to be resolved as a method of `Child`.

Instead Pycharm has a visual warning `Unresolved attribute reference 'foo' for class 'AbstractParent'`
Why isn't it able to figure out that `x` is a `Child` which has method `foo`?

Note that setting `self.x = x` in `B` fixes the issue. Is this a bug?

Comment: Statically, you don't know the type of `self.x`, because the method `super().__init__` is determined by the runtime value of `self.__mro__`.

Comment: @chepner can you think of any way to help the static type checker out here so that the type of `x` is resolved to be `Child`?

Comment: Set `self.x = x` explicitly after the call to `super.__init__()`?

Answer (score 1):

It could be solved with generics, see the following example:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T", bound=AbstractParent)


class A(Generic[T]):
    x: T
    
    def __init__(self, x: T):
        self.x = x


class B(A[Child]):
    def __init__(self, x):
        super().__init__(x=x)

    def test(self):
        return self.x.foo()
```

Feel free to ask any questions.